Cannot load kernel newer than 5.15
System: Ubuntu server 22.04.4 on UEFI
Booting kernel: 5.15
After much reading I am still stuck at not being able to load kernels newer than 5.15. When interrupting GRUB, I do not see any options to load kernels such as 6.8.0 or 6.8.1 that have been downloaded
I see the related files for these systems in /boot but have no idea how to add them to GRUB and subsequently load them.
Update-GRUB has no effect on this issue.
Thank you for your help!

This question is similar to: Can I switch to HWE kernel after installation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To get "newer" kernels on a server, you specifically have to install the HWE kernel line. But you should ask yourself why you would need this on a server - personally I have absolutely no reason to use HWE kernels on a server.

How did you install the kernels? Please edit your question adding how you installed them. I assume you installed the .deb files via sudo dpkg -i something*.deb, which should have also automatically run update-grub.

I believe I installed the additional  kernels via apt-update and apt-upgrade. The system is a local RAID, file, HomeAssistant and Lyrion media server. I enabled a limited desktop to give me a local way of managing KVMs visually.

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server by default installs with the more stable GA kernel stack; ie. 5.15, and remains on that for the life of the product (Server users by default want stability) by design. What are you expecting?  You can switch to the HWE kernel stack if you wish?  or you have done that? and have issues with it. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  Your question isn't clear; and appears to be your misunderstanding what you're running (a Server install it appears, not a Desktop install).

I had purposely built a RAID server install for the usage requirement listed above. Samba, media, Homeassistant in KVM. I added the GUI later because I found that managing the VM via SSH or other to be a PITA.  My question originated from the messages frequently received from a SSh login for updating purposes that newer kernels exist but are not auto-loaded and reboots were required. Also from my noticing that newer kernel packages had been automatically downloaded.
